# ISO file (CDFS) with dramatic overload (~500%)

Tags: filesystems, iso-image, udf

A few years ago I started archiving my old PC games so I can get rid of the actual physical CDs.

A few days ago I wanted to play one of those old games, copied CD content to HDD so I don't have to switch between images while gaming (and edited a ini file so those files will get found).

Although everything worked fine, I noticed that there's a huge difference between the files copied to my HDD (about 3GB) and to those on the cd (700  MB). The CDs are in CDFS and so I first tried to convert to UDF by using UltraISO but the resulting ISO also had about 3 GB.

Does anyone know how come the content of a CD expands to about 500% of the original data size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`man 8 mkisofs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkisofs):

> `-cache-inodes`
>   Cache inode and device numbers to find hard links to files. If `mkisofs` finds a hard link (a file with multiple names), then the file will only appear once on the CD. This helps to save space on the CD.

This means in general there may be hardlinked files on a CD. If so, simply copying all the files will break hardlinks and make every resulting file on HDD take space on its own.

Comment: So is there any way to bring those files out of the image on HDD so I wouldn't have to switch images when a CD change is required?

Comment: @Moldevort In Linux I would just copy files from the CD, like you did, but [in the right way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44247/108618) (although I'm not 100% sure it would work with CDFS). Another approach is to deduplicate later (examples for Windows [here](https://superuser.com/q/345746/432690) – I don't know if these are good though). There is also [NTFS deduplication](https://serverfault.com/q/827853), I don't know if it's available in all Windows OSes.